# удаление строчки в базе SQL с прошедшей датой

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица в базе SQL, где внесенные данные имеют свою дату.
Нужно периодически удалять данные, дата которых оказалась в прошлом.
Я написал так, где `wr_date` - это дата записи в SQL:

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM `table` WHERE DAYOFYEAR(wr_date) < DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE ())", $result);
```

Не работает, и кроме того, я думаю, появятся проблемы при смене года.

Comment: Какой тип у поля `wr_date`?

Comment: varchar(10) Надо датой определять?

Comment: Да, даты должны быть датами. Хотябы CHAR, но уж точно не VARCHAR (почитайте про отличия этих типов).

Answer (score 1):

В общем случае решение простое:

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE date_field < NOW()
```

Для "старее недели":

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE date_field < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK
```

Всё зависит от типа и формата хранимых дат. Используйте нативные типа DATETIME или DATE, и проблем не будет.

Comment: поправил тип поля, поставил date. ЗАРАБОТАЛО, но стерла текущую дату, а этого бы не хотелось. Тогда наверно дописать "- INTERVAL 1 DAY"

Comment: Спасибо выручили. Улётная оперативность.

Comment: Текущую стёрла наверное потому что в поле таблицы лежит дата, а `now()` вернул дату-время и все текущие даты тоже вроде как "меньше дата-времени". Попробуй вместо `< now()` подставить `< CURRENT_DATE()`. Либо всегда можно привести даты к нужному формату `DATE_FORMAT(date_field, '%Y-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(any_datetime_getter(), '%Y-%m-%d')`, но такие запросы не будут использовать индекс и от того будут медленными.